# Render turns out blurred in composite

Tags: rendering, blur

I made this animation, but when it renders it comes out very blurry. I think I did something in the render layers, but I can't figure out what. I tried reset everything to default settings etc. I changed and tried every setting I could think of, copied the animation to a new file, loaded without UI, checked and unchecked different settings.
But when I render the end result is as I said very blurry. But when I change the view from composite to viewlayer everything looks oke. I never had this before.
Anyone knows what causes this?
Thank you.

[image: Blurry result composite view]

[image: Same render in Layer View]

[.Blendfile](https://easyupload.io/6a7jp4)

Comment: You have a blur node in your compositing view. Removing this removes the blur.

Comment: @siljelb  Oooh, so simple. Never thought of that! Thank you so much! I tried everything except that the passed 2 hours. I was getting frustrated, but you made my day again!

Comment: No worries! It's easy to overlook these things in your own work. :)

Comment: :-D I think it was set in the planet settings. I downloaded the planets and only animated them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a blur node in your compositing view. Removing this removes the blur.[image]